# Does the following Scala code make sense?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I got next line

```scala
val students = students_df
  .select(col("name"))
  .distinct
  .map(_.getString(0))
  .collect
  .toSeq
```

My question here is, does the collect really make sense? I've understood that collect and map are kind of the same function. So I want to see if that's correct and why.

In case it is not the most efficent way to work. How should I modifify the code? Just removing the collect?

Thanks in advance

Comment: That `collect` is the **Spark** one, not the stdlib one. Which is not equivalent to `map` but rather, as the name says, collects all the distributed data into an in-memory collection. Usually, you would avoid it.

Comment: In addition to @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez 's point, it's not clear what you want to do with it and it'd be useful if you could add your use case, collect _may_ be the right thing, but if you need results [toLocalIterator](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#toLocalIterator():java.util.Iterator[T]) is probably more sensible.  You should however ask what you are doing with those names, if you are going to do another query or lookup etc. leave them in the dataset and broadcast instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said:

> ```scala
> val students = students_df
>   .select(col("name"))
>   .distinct
>   .map(_.getString(0))
>   .collect
>   .toSeq
> ```
>
> I've understood that collect and map are kind of the same function.

which is not exactly correct in this case. Sounds like you are confusing

- [RDD.collect()](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.html#collect%5BU%5D(f:PartialFunction%5BT,U%5D)(implicitevidence$30:scala.reflect.ClassTag%5BU%5D):org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD%5BU%5D)

> ```scala
> def collect(): Array[T]
> ```
>
> Return an array that contains all of the elements in this RDD.
>
> ##### Note
>
> This method should only be used if the resulting array is expected to be small, as all the data is loaded into the driver's memory.

with this other one

- [RDD.collect(PartialFunction)](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.html#collect%5BU%5D(f:PartialFunction%5BT,U%5D)(implicitevidence$30:scala.reflect.ClassTag%5BU%5D):org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD%5BU%5D)

> ```scala
> def collect[U](f: PartialFunction[T, U])(implicit arg0: ClassTag[U]): RDD[U]
> ```
>
> Return an RDD that contains all matching values by applying f.

The first one gather all the data you have collected and load it in memory, the second one is similar to apply `filter` and `map`.

In the code provided as example, `collect` and `map` are not the same. You would need to pass a `PartialFunction` to do something similar to `map`. Like this

```scala
val students = students_df
  .select(col("name"))
  .distinct
  .map(_.getString(0))
  .collect {
    // the `if` here is for filtering and what I returned after 
    // the `=>` is the transformation
    case x if x == "" => "Empty" 
    // here I am getting the rest of rows and not applying any 
    // transformation. If you don't do that, all the values that
    // aren't caught by this partial function will be discarded 
    // like in the `filter` method
    case x => x 
  }
  .toSeq
```

Then you asked

> In case it is not the most efficent way to work. How should I modifify the code? Just removing the collect?

No context was provided in your question. Which means it's impossible to say if what you did is **the most efficent** approach.

---

**Spark By Examples** is a good blog with many posts showing examples and details about how to use spark in different situations. One of those posts is [Collect() – Retrieve data from Spark RDD/DataFrame](https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-dataframe-collect/)

> ##### collect()
>
> Spark `collect()` and `collectAsList()` are action operation that is used to retrieve all the elements of the RDD/DataFrame/Dataset (from all nodes) to the driver node. We should use the collect() on smaller dataset usually after filter(), group(), count() e.t.c. Retrieving on larger dataset results in out of memory.

also if you look at the API docs, you can see the same warning about not using that method on large datasets

- [RDD.collect()](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.html#collect():Array%5BT%5D)

> ```scala
> def collect(): Array[T]
> ```
>
> Return an array that contains all of the elements in this RDD.
>
> **Note**: This method should only be used if the resulting array is expected to be small, as all the data is loaded into the driver's memory.

- [Dataset.collect()](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.4.1/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#collect():Array%5BT%5D)

> ```scala
> def collect(): Array[T]
> ```
>
> Returns an array that contains all rows in this `Dataset`.
>
> Running collect requires moving all the data into the application's driver process, and doing so on a very **large dataset can crash the driver** process with `OutOfMemoryError`.

Be careful when you are using this method. Maybe [RDD.toLocalIterator](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.html#toLocalIterator:Iterator%5BT%5D) would be better.